# Git crash while using intelliJ: "git.exe - Bad Image"

Tags: windows, git, intellij-idea

So this just happened after using git on current machine for months. I copied a directory inside intelliJ and my git crashed.
git-gui gives `git.exe - Bad Image`, intellij gives `git.exe - Bad Image`, command line git commands don't respond.

[image]

Has anyone encountered this before? What could be the cause of it?

Comment: Have you tried reinstall `git`? Sometimes it's as simple as that.

Comment: @chade_ just reinstalled, that seems to have fixed it. It's still worrying that git core dll file can get corrupted  for unknown reasons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Comments:

> Have you tried reinstall `git`? Sometimes it's as simple as that.

Response:

> just reinstalled, that seems to have fixed it. It's still worrying that git core dll file can get corrupted for unknown reasons.

I'm answering this so other users with the same problem can easily determine the answer that was provided.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the similar issue. It was solved after I reinstalled the git. I do not know the exact reason why the git file has already corrupted. But this solved the issue for me.
Please go to this link at  https://git-for-windows.github.io/ to download git for windows.